# Toggle multiple topmenu's in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to toggle multiple menu's in my fixed top menu.
For some reason it is not working with data-parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tz8BD/3/

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default topmenu" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-parent=".topmenu">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>

       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" data-parent=".topmenu">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
   </div>

       <div class="collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <h1>test toggle 1</h1>
       </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="topmenu">
   <div class="collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
     <h1>test toggle 2</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, with some custom code.
Toggling between multiple boxes seems to be only supported for .panel elements in Bootstrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tz8BD/6/

```
$('.topToggler').click(function(){
        var $this   = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('data-target');
        var $target = $(target);
        var parent = $this.attr('data-parent');
        var $parent = $(parent)

        $this[$target.hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')

        $target.collapse('toggle')
        $parent.find('.topToggler').not($this).addClass('collapsed');

        var actives = $parent.find('.in')
        if (actives && actives.length) {
          actives.collapse('hide')
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/Tz8BD/4/

```
 <div class="collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <h1>test toggle 1</h1>
    </div>
```

put this div out side nav. Use button onclick `onclick="$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').slideToggle('slow');"`

Comment: Hmm, I meant that when I open collapse 1, it has to close collapse 2., and the other way around. Data-target is working correctly